# Deploy application with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I'm trying to deploy my application with Capistrano for the first time but i keep getting this error:

```
cat: /var/rails/app/current/REVISION: No such file or directory
```

It is normal as i don't have a current revision yet. I just launched the following commands:

```
cap deploy:setup
cap deploy:cold
```

I don't know what i'm missing, so any help would be appreciated.

Salim

Comment: Please add the full error trace so that the source of the problem can be identified. If the error is from the `* executing 'deploy:assets:precompile'` line as in https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/224, then the workaround of removing `load deploy/assets` line from deploy.rb file in the first deploy should work.